# mvn 3.0.4 don't support wildcard * in exclusion?

Tags: maven, wildcard

my maven version is 3.0.4, while when I use wildcard in dependency exclusion. No matter in groupID field or arifactID field, it give out warning that :

value '*' does not match a valid id pattern.

And it did fail to exclude those jar.

I googled and it seems someone mentioned that 3.0.3 already support wildcard? if this is not true, from which version it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you found that Maven 3.0.3 is supporting wildcard exclusion in dependency.  From http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3832 seems suggests to me that is only available in Maven 3.2

Comment: The jira link becomes https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3832 now